# Elasticsearch pattern regex start with

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I would like to ask if exists some documentation which describe how to work with **Elasticseach pattern regex**.

I need to write **Pattern Capture Token Filter** which filter only tokes start with specific word. For example input tokens stream should be like (*"abcefgh", "abc123" , "aabbcc", "abc", "abdef"*) and my tokenizer will return only tokes **abcefgh** , **abc123**, **abc**  because those tokens start with "**abc**".

Can someone help me how to achieve this use-case?

Thanks.

Comment: The regex is easy - `abc.*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest something like this:

```
"analysis": {
  "analyzer": {
    "my_trim_keyword_analyzer": {
      "type": "custom",
      "tokenizer": "keyword",
      "filter": [
        "lowercase",
        "trim",
        "generate_tokens",
        "eliminate_tokens",
        "remove_empty"
      ]
    }
  },
  "filter": {
    "eliminate_tokens": {
      "pattern": "^(?!abc)\\w+$",
      "type": "pattern_replace",
      "replacement": ""
    },
    "generate_tokens": {
      "type": "pattern_capture",
      "preserve_original": 1,
      "patterns": [
        "(([a-z]+)(\\d*))"
      ]
    },
    "remove_empty": {
      "type": "stop",
      "stopwords": [""]
    }
  }
}
```

If your tokens are the result of a `pattern_capture` filter, you'd need to add after this filter the one called `eliminate_tokens` in my example which basically matches token that don't start with `abc`. Those that don't match are replaced by empty string (`"replacement": ""`).

After this, to remove the empty tokens I added the `remove_empty` filter which is basically a `stop` filter where the stopword is `""` (empty string).

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I tried this out and its work! May i have one more question? What if i want get words started with "abc" OR "bca" OR "gdfh" ?

Comment: You change the regex for `eliminate_tokens` filter: `^(?!(abc|bca|gdfh))\\w+$`

Comment: Thanks, so easy! Really helpfull!